# How to check and read my Master Key generated using DP API

Tags: dpapi

The query is regarding the DP API functionality.
I am using DP API Protect and Unprotect method to encrypt my string with a secret entropy. As per the information available on internet , a Master key is generated by DP API initially which is stored at Appdata\roaming\Microsoft\protect[SID]\"***mymasterkeyfile***" . 
On program execution , SID folder is generated on my system but I am not able to find master key file. I Don't know why?
I am new to this so not able to understand the issue.

Any help appreciated,Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It's a (hidden) system file so adapt your folder settings to make these visible ( probably only to admins). In the Console (as admin) use `dir /A:HS [folder]` to see the files, which have long random names.